# Exit #!/usr/bin/expect when Status was VPN tunnel closed

Tags: tcl, expect

i am using an expect script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set force_conservative 0  ;
if {$force_conservative} {
   set send_slow {1 .1}
   proc send {ignore arg} {
           sleep .1
           exp_send -s -- $arg
   }
}
set timeout -1
spawn $env(SHELL)
match_max 100000
send -- "cd /home/forticlientsslvpn/64bit/\r"
send -- "./forticlientsslvpn --server ip:port --vpnuser UN"
expect -exact "./forticlientsslvpn --server ip:PORT  --vpnuser UN"
send -- "\r"
expect -exact "\r
Password for VPN:"
send -- "PW\r"
expect -exact "\r
STATUS::Setting up the tunnel\r
STATUS::Connecting...\r"
send -- "Y\r"
expect eof
```

file which will connect VPN,
when VPN connection is successful it will display `STATUS::Tunnel running`,
But when connection closed, `STATUS will be Tunnel closed`  and still the script will keep on running

````
STATUS::Stopping tunnel
STATUS::Tunnel closed...```

How to exit the script when we get ```STATUS::Tunnel closed```
````

Comment: There's a distinct lack of code in this question.

Comment: @Shawn I have added the code please check

Comment: Much better now, thanks.

Comment: @Shawn any suggestions on this?

Comment: Maybe an expect command that waits for that string or eof instead of just eof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding expect Stopping and expect closed in the last lines of the script will exit the script.

```
expect Stopping
expect closed
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you spawn a *shell*, and when the vpn client closes, the shell is still running.

Spawn the vpn client directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
cd /home/forticlientsslvpn/64bit
spawn ./forticlientsslvpn --server ip:port --vpnuser UN
match_max 100000
expect "Password for VPN:"
send -- "PW\r"
expect "STATUS::Connecting..."
send -- "Y\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: Greetings @glenn jackman requesting your support on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406140/11096022 when you have a minute

Comment: What do you want me to do there?